# How to setup a DHT server of bittorrent?

Tags: bittorrent, dht

I am finding a way to setup my own DHT bootstrap server of bittorrent on a linux server. I tried bootstrap-dht, but I found it didn't work. It is designed to create your own DHT network instead of introducing the client to the **bittorrent** DHT network.

Anyone can help?

Comment: You need to use the `--x-pollinate ` option to another bootstrap node to 'join' them

Comment: Yes, I found this --x-pollinate before and tried it, I will try it again.